# What is the cause of the errors "'timer0_pin_port'" and "'_vector_13'"?

Tags: c++, arduino

```
#include "IRremote.h"

int receiver = 11;

IRrecv irReceiver(receiver);
decode_results results;

void setup() {
  // put your setup code here, to run once:
pinMode(buttonPinA, INPUT_PULLUP);
pinMode(buttonPinB, INPUT_PULLUP);
pinMode(buttonPinC, INPUT_PULLUP);
pinMode(buttonPinD, INPUT_PULLUP);
irReceiver.enableIRIn();
}
```

The error message is:

> **Tone.cpp.o (symbol from plugin): In function `timer0_pin_port':**
>
> (.text+0x0): **multiple definition of `__vector_13'**
>
> libraries\IRremote\IRremote.cpp.o (symbol from plugin):(.text+0x0):
>   first defined here
>
> c:/program files
>   (x86)/arduino/hardware/tools/avr/bin/../lib/gcc/avr/4.9.2/../../../../avr/bin/ld.exe:
>   Disabling relaxation: it will not work with multiple definitions
>
> collect2.exe: error: ld returned 1 exit status
>
> **exit status 1** Error compiling for board Arduino/Genuino Mega or Mega
>   2560.

I have recently discovered that "tone" and "IRremote" commands use timer2 from [here](https://forum.arduino.cc/index.php?topic=120955.0). I am unaware of what timer2 really is and how to change it.

Comment: Do you have any definitions in your `IRremote.h` header file?

Comment: You should explain for problem more deeply than sharing code and error message

Comment: I'll bet you could remove at least 90% of that code and still get the problem. Don't ask people to wade through all that irrelevant stuff; condense it as much as you can.

Answer (score 1):

This error is a **link**-time issue.  Two pieces of library code have both declared something with the same name (in this case it's a timer).

So the compilation was all OK, and now the linker is taking the compiled output and is wrapping it into an executable.  Every time you see an error message like  `error: ld returned ...`, know it's a link problem, and not a syntax issue.  Anything `ld` is the linker ("ld" is the name of the linker program).

As described here:

https://forum.arduino.cc/index.php?topic=120955.msg2613823#msg2613823

Edit the header file IRRemote.h and change which timer interrupt the library uses:

Change the selection:

```
#define IR_USE_TIMER1   // tx = pin 9
// #define IR_USE_TIMER2     // tx = pin 3
```

e.g.:

```
// #define IR_USE_TIMER1   // tx = pin 9
#define IR_USE_TIMER2     // tx = pin 3
```

Comment: This makes sense, but that is located in the IRRemoteInt.h header. When I change it from timer2 to timer1 and make the sketch include IRremoteInt.h, it does not recognize the IRrecv object or any other part from IRremote.h. When I include both, The same original error message pops up..

Comment: @TheRyGuy - It may help to find the other code module which is causing the issue too.  Keep commenting out includes and blocks of code until the error goes away.  Maybe you can make a similar patch in the other library.  It's a tedious method, but it works.

Comment: What do the pin numbers mean to the right of the definitions?

Comment: @TheRyGuy - There's a hardware interrupt on Pin 2 & 3, I'm not sure about pin 9 - maybe this lecture helps:  https://courses.cs.washington.edu/courses/csep567/10wi/lectures/Lecture7.pdf